# Renewcommand not working

Tags: macros

I have a tex file compiling with no errors or warnings.

But when I add this line:

```
\newcommand{\mag}{randomstr}
```

I get this error:

```
LaTeX Error: Command \mag already defined. [\newcommand{\mag}{randomstr}]
```

So, I try to change it to this:

```
\renewcommand{\mag}{randomstr}
```

but get all of these errors too:

```
report.tex:32: Missing number, treated as zero. [\begin{document}]
report.tex:32: Missing = inserted for \ifnum. [\begin{document}]
report.tex:32: Missing number, treated as zero. [\begin{document}]
report.tex:32: Missing $ inserted. [\begin{document}]
report.tex:32: Missing number, treated as zero. [\begin{document}]
report.tex:32: Missing = inserted for \ifnum. [\begin{document}]
report.tex:32: Missing number, treated as zero. [\begin{document}]
report.tex:32: You can't use `the letter r' after \the. [\begin{document}]
report.tex:33: Missing $ inserted. []
```

I have also tried the `\def` directive, but with no result. Any idea how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: This is because `\mag` is a TeX primitive used in setting magnification levels of fonts. You should use an alternative macro for your definition of `randomstr`.

Comment: So, you're basically saying I can't redefine the `\mag` command in any way right?

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm saying. Perhaps you can elude more to why you're trying to use `\mag` and not something else? Would `\Mag` work?

Comment: It makes sense to use `\mag`, because of the context of what I am writing, but `\Mag` or `\MAG` work just as well. Just finding out latex commands are case sensitive, no idea before.

Answer (score 9):

This is because `\mag` is a TeX *primitive* used in setting magnification levels of fonts. While you are able to change it, it has disastrous consequences, since it's used in its original setting, which you've adjusted. Translated into more colloquial terms, this would be like deciding to change the fuel used in your car, since it suits your wallet better. So, instead of using petrol, you opt for diesel (say). The car still *requires* petrol to run without further modification, regardless of *your* preference, causing major problems (either immediately, or down the road).<sup>*</sup>

The solution: Do not redefine a TeX primitive (via `\renewcommand`, `\def`, or the like). You should use an alternative macro for your definition of `randomstr`. For example,

```
\newcommand{\Mag}{randomstr}
```

should work, since control sequences (macros) are case-sensitive.

<sub><sup>*</sup> In the above discussion, the car/engine is (La)TeX, petrol is `\mag` and diesel is the "redefinition of `\mag`".</sub>

Comment: Follow-up question: How do you know it's a TeX primitive? Don't seem to be able to figure that from the error log.

Comment: And in the same line: I guess `\cal` would be the same case, a TeX primitive, since I am getting the same error, correct?

Comment: @nunos Try `\show\mag`: you get `\mag=\mag`. Primitives 'are themselves'.

Comment: @nunos no \cal isn't a primitive but it doesn't matter really, if `\newcommand` tells you a command is defined you shouldn't redefine it unless you know what the original definition is used for. `\begin` isn't a primitive but if you redefine it most of latex will break.

Comment: @nunos The golden rule is: don't redefine a command unless you know *precisely* what it does.